# negligable voltage at receptacle

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I replaced my kitchen faucet the oter day and when I hooked the garbage disposal back up to it's dedicated outlet, nothing happened.  Next, I plugged a lamp into the outlet and flipped on the switch for the disposer - still nothing.  Then I removed the outlet and checked the incomming wires with a voltmeter; <10 volts indicated when the circuit was energized.
  I checked the circuit breaker with a voltmeter and it indicated a full 120 volts.  What's going on?
  All other kitchen outlets are working and the single GFI is not tripped.

Answer (score 3):

**Daisy-chained receptacles with GFCI**

Check every receptacle in the kitchen. Very likely one of them has tripped, possibly due to water getting on the disposal receptacle when you were working on the faucet. Reset it and your problem will most likely be resolved. The GFCI could be elsewhere, but my bet is "everything involved is in the kitchen".

Comment: If this is it, also note that you missed a breaker that you should have turned off - that GFCI could have saved your life.

Comment: Anything possible. But arguably, if OP was working on faucet and not intending to deal with anything electrical, unplugging the disposal was a convenience but not a safety necessity. Last time I replaced one of my kitchen faucets, I didn't even think of turning off power to the disposal, though my disposals are hardwired so it is a little different. On the other hand, when I replaced a disposal, yes I did make sure power was 100% off.